# What is "asynchronous exception handling"

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

What is this new "asynchronous exception handling" API that I keep seeing mentioned as part of ruby 2.0.

Can someone please explain, roughly, what is meant by "asynchronous exception handling" in ruby?

Comment: Not just for ruby, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling

Comment: @user1929959 the only pertinent part of your linked article is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Exception_synchronicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "asynchronous exception handling API" is essentially this new method: [`Thread::handle_interrupt`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html#method-c-handle_interrupt) coupled with [class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html#method-c-pending_interrupt-3F) and [instance](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html#method-i-pending_interrupt-3F) versions of `pending_interrupt?`.  It's an attempt to give some finer control over what can happen when one uses `Thread#raise` or `Thread#kill`.